# Windows ssh default location for idrsa (git install)

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I have git installed on my windows 7 PC
I have ssh.exe installed in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe
```

It is also in my path.

The following command works and connects me to my server:

```
ssh -i%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/id_rsa maven_repo@mvnsnap.metcarob.com -p7345
```

however if I run

```
ssh maven_repo@mvnsnap.metcarob.com -p7345
```

I am prompted to enter a password. I need this to work to run maven goals successfully. I want to be able to specify a default idrsa location.

Intrestingly ssh-keygen outputs the following when I run it:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)>ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (//.ssh/id_rsa):
```

It seems to have failed to get the %USERPROFILE% location. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that I must set a user environment variable called HOME and ssh picks this up